# What is the difference between ctx.end() and next()?

Tags: hook, loopbackjs, connector

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `next()` and `ctx.end()` in  [connector hooks of loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Connector-hooks.html#before-execute).

Moreover, why the `ctx.end()` function cannot be used for other hooks?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a while :

- First, next() and ctx.end() **do share the same signature**.
- If *several* observers are bound to the connector, they are called one after the other (by order of binding).

  - Calling next() calls the next observer
  - Calling ctx.end() ends "closes" the event

Example-1 (coffee) :

```
connectorName.connector.observe 'after execute', (ctx, next) ->
    console.log "hook1", new Date()
    wait(3000)
    ctx.end null, ctx, ctx.res.body
connectorName.connector.observe 'after execute', (ctx, next) ->
    console.log "hook2", new Date()
    wait(3000)
    next()
```

Example-2 (coffee) :

```
connectorName.connector.observe 'after execute', (ctx, next) ->
    console.log "hook1", new Date()
    wait(3000);
    next null, ctx, ctx.res.body
connectorName.connector.observe 'after execute', (ctx, next) ->
    console.log "hook2", new Date()
    wait(3000)
    next()
```

In the first example, the second hook is never called. In the second it is normally called.

```
pgConnector.connector.observe 'after execute', (ctx, next) ->
    console.log "hook2", new Date()
    wait(3000);
    ctx.end(null, ctx.res)

pgConnector.connector.observe 'after execute', (ctx, next) ->
    console.log "hook3", new Date()
    wait(3000);
    next()
```

Same here with database connector.

Comment: It is only for rest api connector. For other connectors, this is not true.

Comment: **do share the same signature** is just relevant for rest api connector. For others they are the **same**

Comment: @Ebrahim Please, if you don't know, if you're not sure of what you say, do not answer as if your words were the absolut truth. I lost precious time because of that

Answer (score 1):

Because they are the same if the `end` function not defined.

There is some piece of code in loopback datasource juggler :

```
if (context.end === undefined) {
    context.end = callback;
  }
```

You can check it out on [this line](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/5bf18b07280e22d713e722b8e23f8aee14c6587e/lib/observer.js#L141)

So it's the same that which one you use.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Connector-hooks.html#before-execute), the ctx.end() function and next() do not share the same arguments. I reckon `next` can only be called with an `err`, whereas `ctx.end` accepts `err, results`.
Moreover, after reading what you sent [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/5bf18b07280e22d713e722b8e23f8aee14c6587e/lib/observer.js#L145), it seems `next` goes to the next observer, whereas `ctx.end` just ends.

Comment: @Gabriel No it's the same here.

Comment: I tested it more thoroughly, it seems you're right. `next` can be called with the same arguments. But why `ctx.end` is not available in other hooks like remote hooks?

Comment: @Gabriel It means in connector context. Ending in remote hooks may causes some problems. There are some middlewares and ending the response should occur through the middlewares, as we have an error handler middleware too.